# How to handle deeper library hierarchies in Dart?

Tags: dart

The basic usage of a library is by defining its name like:

```
#library('Name');
```

In my case, I'd like to define "nested" or "deeper" library hierarchies. So if I had a framework called `Foo` and let's say I build library `Messenger`:

```
#library('Messenger');
```

I'm afraid that would conflict with something else. What I'm looking for is something like:

```
#import('Foo.Messenger');
```

So that it's clear the messenger library is part of a Foo set of libraries.

What's the recommended way to approach this? As I understand, people would refer to your library like:

```
#import('package:Foo.Messenger')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Librarires will change soon, see http://news.dartlang.org/2012/07/draft-spec-changes-to-library-and.html. Note that your question is answered in this document, as it says: *Names of libraries intended for widespread use should follow the well known reverse internet domain name convention.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned that your library may conflict with a namespace, then a prefix needs to be defined when using it. However you cannot force that someone else use a prefix when using your library.

To use a prefix yourself you would import like this:

```
#import('lib/library.dart', prefix: 'myLib');
```

Now anything imported from that library needs to be called as such:

```
var item = new myLib.SomeClass();
```

See this [link](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/language-tour/#using-libraries) for further details.

A package, as defined in your last night of your question, is a means of distributing and importing 3rd party libraries which may be one or many. It is still undergoing a lot of development, but it will not change how your library is called once it is imported.

See this [link](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/pub-package-manager/) for information on the Pub Package manager in Dart.

Comment: I understand packages I've done two so far. I also know about the prefix I've read the language tour and specs, but what I don't know is how to avoid conflicts with *library names*. That is, there's a purpose for why you write `#library(...);`. The names are for example used in reflection (upcoming feature).

Comment: Correct, but you import by file name, not by library name. Library names are internal identifiers. If you wish you can use something similar to the 'core' files and name your libraries such as:

    #library("packageName:lib1")
    #library("packageName:lib2")

 etc. However, you will not import by that name you define.